# I tried to strip down synthetix staking contract

Tags: solidity

So i'm trying to recreate synthetixs staking contract without the rewards function/distribution.. just a stake/unstake contract for a token i will be deploying, I haven't specified the specific token address to be staked but I am just trying to deploy the stake contract to test with any token..

I currently have this-

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/math/Math.sol";
import "https://github.com/ConsenSysMesh/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.0/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";


contract StakingRewards is ReentrancyGuard {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    /* ========== STATE VARIABLES ========== */

    IERC20 public stakingToken;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;
    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;

    /* ========== CONSTRUCTOR ========== */

    constructor(
        address _owner,
        address _stakingToken
    ) public Owned(_owner) {
        stakingToken = IERC20(_stakingToken);
    }

    /* ========== VIEWS ========== */

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }


    /* ========== MUTATIVE FUNCTIONS ========== */

    function stake(uint256 amount) external nonReentrant notPaused updateReward(msg.sender) {
        require(amount > 0, "Cannot stake 0");
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount);
        _balances[msg.sender] = _balances[msg.sender].add(amount);
        stakingToken.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        emit Staked(msg.sender, amount);
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 amount) public nonReentrant updateReward(msg.sender) {
        require(amount > 0, "Cannot withdraw 0");
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(amount);
        _balances[msg.sender] = _balances[msg.sender].sub(amount);
        stakingToken.safeTransfer(msg.sender, amount);
        emit Withdrawn(msg.sender, amount);
    }

    
    /* ========== EVENTS ========== */

    event Staked(address indexed user, uint256 amount);
    event Withdrawn(address indexed user, uint256 amount);
}
```

however, I am getting a few warnings upon compiling which i cant seem to identify.

> warning 1 -SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before
> publishing, consider adding a comment containing
> "SPDX-License-Identifier: " to each source file. Use
> "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code.
>
> warning 2 -ParserError: Source file requires different compiler
> version (current compiler is 0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.Emscripten.clang) -
> note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the
> released version
>
> warning 3-  Source file requires different compiler version (current
> compiler is 0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.Emscripten.clang) - note that
> nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released
> version

Answer (score 1):

you are receiving wrong compiler error. You are using ^0.8.0 compiler version but your imported contracts compiler version are:

Math.sol compiler version is ^0.8.0

SafeMath.sol compiler version is ^0.4.23

SafeERC20.sol compiler version is >=0.6.0 <0.8.0

ReentrancyGuard.sol compiler version is ^0.8.0

Unfortunately there is no version of compiler to use to support all of those contracts. So you must find contracts which at least they support one version of compiler. Best regards.